# Gemfile not found when running Cron job with Capistrano 3 and whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, whenever

My cron job works fine on my local machine after running `whenever -w`, after deploy to my VPS, I get this error, `release 20150415044915 doesn't exist`. any idea?

I looked at my crontab -e, the path also looks fine where 20150502114703 is the correct release:

```
0 1 * * 1 /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/hey_production/releases/20150502114703 && bin/rails runner ....
```

Error Log:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:22:in `build': /home/hey_production/releases/20150415044915/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:154:in `definition'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  from bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The `Gemfile` will be found under the `current` folder of the release path. i.e. at `/home/hey_production/releases/20150415044915/current/Gemfile` - not  `/home/hey_production/releases/20150415044915/Gemfile`.

Comment: It should point to `/home/hey_production/current/Gemfile`. Release *20150415044915* might get cleaned up in the future.

Comment: I dont understand the down vote.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy `/home/hey_production/current` points to the release  `/home/hey_production/releases/20150415044915`. Not the other way around. Or am i mistaken?
The `/home/hey_production/releases/20150415044915` folder would not have any `current` directory because its a release.

Comment: can you attach the log output from `/var/log/cron`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the environment variable is missing that tells the cron where to look for a Gemfile. so you need to add that variable in your environment at the time when cron tries to run this.
You can do that in Your `schedule.rb`:

```
env BUNDLE_GEMFILE, ENV["/home/hey_production/current/Gemfile"]
```

or directly inside crontab file with the command `crontab -e`(before the cron entries):

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE="/home/hey_production/current/Gemfile"
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**
Forgot the symbol above in `schedule.rb`

The line in `schedule.rb` should be like this.

```
env :BUNDLE_GEMFILE, ENV["/#{path}/Gemfile"]
```

or

```
env :BUNDLE_GEMFILE, ENV["/home/hey_production/current/Gemfile"]
```

Comment: Thanks, insert BUNDLE_GEMFILE="/home/hey_production/current/Gemfile"   into crontab -e works, and env BUNDLE_GEMFILE, ENV["/home/hey_production/current/Gemfile"]  raise BUNDLE_GEMFILE undefined when I deploy using Capistrano, any idea?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure of the syntax in the schedule file. I will get back to you soon with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up on previous answer, set the env variable in whenever inside **schedule.rb** before the schedule blocks like:

```
def production?
  @environment == 'production'
end

set :output, {:error => '/home/current/log/cron_error.log', :standard => '/home/current/log/cron.log'}

every 2.hour, roles: [:utility] do
  runner "/home/current/lib/cron_jobs/launch_pending_emails.rb"
end
```

and inside your `deploy.rb` environment specific file ie: `staging.rb` set the env:

```
set :whenever_roles, [:utility]
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
set(:whenever_command) { "STAGE=#{stage} bundle exec whenever" }
require 'whenever/capistrano'
```